# How do I find duplicate rows and remove all but one based on the value of one column?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `df` that looks like this

```
c1 c2
A  1
A  2
A  3
B  1
```

I want column to find all rows where `c1` has duplicate values, and keep only the row with the highest `c2` value.

The result would look like this:

Comment: `aggregate(c2 ~ c1, df, max)`

Comment: If your data is sorted by `c2`, then `df[!duplicated(df$C1, fromLast = T), ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have the two columns in your data frame, the function `aggregate` can do this pretty easily:

```
aggregate(c2 ~ c1, data = df, FUN = max)
```

`aggregate` executes the function `FUN` on `data` based on the groups described on the right half of the input formula.